# conversion of data.table to data.frame gives error in v1.8.10

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data frames `x` and `y`. The data is shared (in .csv and .RData formats) here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iPCtmOAvwxR0RfYUk1bXFMZEk/edit?usp=sharing

`x` has columns `g` and `x.1`. `y` has columns `g` and `x.0`.

I did the following:

```
x_dt<-data.table(x)
y_dt<-data.table(y)
setkeyv(x_dt,"g")
setkeyv(y_dt,"g")

z_dt<-merge(x_dt,y_dt,by="g",all=T)

z<-as.data.table(z_dt)
```

When I try to see the output of `z`, e.g. `print(z)` or `tail(z)` , I get the following error:

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  dims [product 253] do not match the length of object [254]
```

What could be the issue?

*** EDIT ***

Here is the sessionInfo as per request:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] compiler  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] signal_0.7-3            MASS_7.3-29             TTR_0.22-0              xts_0.9-7              
[5] zoo_1.7-10              RcppRoll_0.1.0          RcppArmadillo_0.4.000.4 Rcpp_0.11.0            
[9] data.table_1.8.10      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-23 tools_3.0.2
```

*** EDIT ***

I `detach`ed `zoo`, `TTR` and `xts` which were loaded but I wasn't using. But the error still persists.

Comment: You're using an older version of `data.table`. The current stable version is 1.9.2. Please update and try again.

Comment: I suggest that you either answer it saying that updating to 1.9.2 fixes the issue or delete this answer, whichever you prefer.

Comment: can you tell me why this occurred in 1.8.10? I have done similar operations multiple times in 1.8.10 and the error didn't happen until now. what changes were made between 1.8.10 and 1.9.2 that could have resolved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating to 1.9.2 fixed the issue. Thanks, Arun!